# incorrect number of dimensions R - rowSums

Tags: r, dimensions

I'm very new to coding so I'm basically googling everything but I couldn't figure this one out:

I have a data frame of 32 rows, and 19 columns. I want to calculate the sum of each row in three specific columns.

I'm writing it like this:

`D10` - my data frame.

`Compliance_score` - the new column I want to add

`Compliance_1-3` - the columns I want to sum

```
D10$Compliance_score = rowSums(D10[ ,c("Compliance_1", "Compliance_2", "Compliance_3"), drop = FALSE])
```

I keep getting the error: `"incorrect number of dimensions".`

Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, or what this error message even means.

Any thoughts?

**editing: if I understood correctly what is a reproduce example (this is my first time, I hope I got this right- if not please let me know)

```
> dput(head(D10))
structure(list(PP = c("003", "014", "047", "013", "053", "048"
), MAAS_1 = c("4.0", "4.0", "3.0", "5.0", "3.0", "4.0"), MAAS_2 = 
c("3.0", 
"1.0", "6.0", "4.0", "3.0", "3.0"), MAAS_3 = c("4.0", "5.0", 
"4.0", "3.0", "4.0", "4.0"), MAAS_4 = c("2.0", "2.0", "6.0", 
"2.0", "3.0", "4.0"), MAAS_5 = c("3.0", "3.0", "4.0", "5.0", 
"5.0", "5.0"), MAAS_6 = c("3.0", "3.0", "4.0", "3.0", "2.0", 
"4.0"), MAAS_7 = c("3.0", "3.0", "4.0", "3.0", "3.0", "5.0"), 
    MAAS_8 = c("2.0", "4.0", "4.0", "4.0", "4.0", "4.0"), MAAS_9 
= c("3.0", 
    "4.0", "3.0", "2.0", "4.0", "5.0"), MAAS_10 = c("3.0", "4.0", 
    "4.0", "2.0", "4.0", "4.0"), MAAS_11 = c("2.0", "5.0", "4.0", 
    "4.0", "1.0", "5.0"), MAAS_12 = c("2.0", "5.0", "6.0", "3.0", 
    "3.0", "6.0"), MAAS_13 = c("3.0", "3.0", "5.0", "3.0", "3.0", 
    "2.0"), MAAS_14 = c("3.0", "4.0", "5.0", "4.0", "4.0", "4.0"
    ), MAAS_15 = c("3.0", "5.0", "6.0", "3.0", "5.0", "5.0"), 
    Compliance_1 = c("0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "1.0", "0.0"
    ), Compliance_2 = c("1.0", "0.0", "1.0", "0.0", "1.0", "0.0"
    ), Compliance_3 = c("0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl",         
"data.frame"
))
>
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: A reproducible example with your data would be great! You can dput() your df object and post in the question.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code. Please provide example data, `dput(head(D10))`, so we can reproduce the error.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this :

```
library(tidyverse)
New_D <- D10 %>%
  mutate(Compliance_score = sum(c(Compliance_1, Compliance_2, Compliance_3), na.rm=TRUE))
```

But a reproducible example would be great to understand the error.

Claire

Comment: When I tries your code I got this: 
error in `sum()`:
! invalid 'type' (character) of argument

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your data is stored as a character, hence you need transform it to the class `numeric` in order to calculate the sum, i.e.

```
library(dplyr)

New_D <- df %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("Compliance"), as.numeric)) %>% 
  mutate(Compliance_score = Compliance_1 + Compliance_2 + Compliance_3)
```

Or with @Claire suggestion when you have NA'values

```
New_D <- df %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("Compliance"), as.numeric)) %>% 
  mutate(Compliance_score = sum(c(Compliance_1, Compliance_2, Compliance_3),
                                na.rm=TRUE))
```